# how to fail testng test on misspelled dataprovider?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, testng

testNg binds data providers by name (a string). when i misspelled it, it returned success. just no tests were run. is there any configuration option to fail-fast in case of such error?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, when a test case does not find its data provider (which happens in your case of misspelled data provider name), that test case is skipped. And therefore, no test is run. What you need is a way to see skipped test cases.

You can print messages or throw exceptions whenever a test is skipped. However, throwing exceptions may not be recommended because it may stop build after the first skipped tests and your entire test suite may remain untested.

**Approach 1**
You need to implement ITestListener which provides method

```
   onTestSkipped(ITestResult testResult)
```

**Approach 2** TestNG also enables you to generate reports at the end of test run. You need to implement

```
 IReporter interface
```

You need to code for generateReport() method.

**In addition** for both the above approaches, you need to configure your implementation class as a listener in testng.xml like following.

```
<listeners>
    <listener class-name="com...test.reporter.TestStatusReporter" />
</listeners>
```

**Next**
Once you run

```
mvn install
```

and is successful, you can view test results including skipped tests details in the following location of your project.

```
../target/surefire-reports/index.html
```

Hope this helps.